# Wrong parse tree while importing multiple grammars

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have following grammars for numbers and date:

**numbers grammar:**

```
    grammar numbers;
    import DateLexer;
    spelled_first_to_thirty_first:
        int_01_to_31_optional_prefix (TH | ND |RD|ST)
        ;
    int_01_to_31_optional_prefix
        : int_01_to_12
        | int_1_to_5
        | int_6_to_9
        | int_13_to_23
        | int_24_to_31
        ;
    int_13_to_23
        :(('1')('3'|'4'|'5'|int_6_to_9))|(('2')('0'|'1'|'2'|'3'))
        ;
    int_01_to_12 
        :(('0')(int_1_to_5|int_6_to_9))|(('1')('0'|'1'|'2'))
        ;
    int_1_to_5
        : '1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'
        ;
    int_6_to_9
        :'6' | '7' | '8' | '9'
        ;
    int_24_to_31
        :(('2')('4'|'5'|int_6_to_9))|(('3')('0'|'1'|'2'))
        ;
```

**date lexer grammar:**

```
        lexer grammar datelex;
        JANUARY   : 'january'   's'?  | 'jan' DOT? ;
        FEBRUARY  : 'february'  's'?  | 'feb' DOT?;
        MARCH     : 'march'     'es'? | 'mar' DOT?;
        APRIL     : 'april'     's'?  | 'apr' DOT?;
        MAY       : 'may'       's'?;
        JUNE      : 'june'      's'?  | 'jun' DOT?;
        JULY      : 'july'      's'?  | 'jul' DOT?;
        AUGUST    : 'august'    's'?  | 'aug' DOT?;
        SEPTEMBER : 'september' 's'?  | 'sep' DOT? | 'sept' DOT?;
        OCTOBER   : 'october'   's'?  | 'oct' DOT?;
        NOVEMBER  : 'november'  's'?  | 'nov' DOT?;
        DECEMBER  : 'december'  's'?  | 'dec' DOT?;
```

**date grammar:**

```
        grammar Date;
        import dateLex,numbers;
        d:day_of_month;

        month
        : JANUARY
        | FEBRUARY
        | MARCH
        | APRIL
        | MAY
        | JUNE
        | JULY
        | AUGUST
        | SEPTEMBER
        | OCTOBER
        | NOVEMBER
        | DECEMBER
        ;

        day_of_month
        : spelled_first_to_thirty_first 'of'? month;
```

first of all I test the numbers grammar with `15th` and i got this parse tree:

`(r (spelled_first_to_thirty_first (int_01_to_31_optional_prefix (int_13_to_23 1 5)) th))`

and it seems right but when i test the date grammar with `15th of sep` i got this pars tree:

```
(d (day_of_month (spelled_first_to_thirty_first (int_01_to_31_optional_prefix (int_1_to_5 1)) 5) of (month sep)))
```

which is wrong because it separates 1 and 5 in `15` and recognize it as a number `1`.
 why this happen? what should i do to fix this problem?

Comment: This seems a bit complicated. Maybe just write what is the parser suppose to parse. I've written one or two parsers with antlr that needed to parse dates and it wasn't this much...

Comment: It feels like I keep repeating myself with every ANTLR question but here it goes: make your parser the *simplest* you can get. The parser needs to handle *syntactic* rules. Then, implement a validation pass with a visitor to check the *semantic* rules. Basically: write *one* `number` rule, and check the number range *after* the parse.